# create xml file using Php Dom

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml, domparser

i am currently creating a xml file using php Dom with this pattern

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
  <dict>
    <Location>None</Location>
    <XOffset>0</XOffset>
    <YOffset>0</YOffset>
  </dict>
</list>
```

and read this by jquery with this code

```
$.post("demo.xml",{},function(xml){
    $('dict',xml).each(function(i) {
    location = $(this).find("Location").text();
        XOffset = $(this).find("XOffset").text();
        YOffset= $(this).find("XOffset").text();

    });
```

but know i want to create xml file like that

```
<key>Location</key>
<string>None</string>
<key>XOffset</key>
<string>0</string>
<key>YOffset</key>
<string>0</string>
```

Anyone have any idea how can i write this in php dom and after that how i can read it back

Comment: I dpn't understand: if you can create XML1, why are you asking how to create XML2?

Comment: creation is not a big problem the main headache is how i can read value say for example Location whose value is None

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

if(!file_exists("book.xml")) {
    $books = $xml->createElement("books");
     
    $newbook = $xml->createElement("book");
    $newbook->appendChild($xml->createElement("title",$_POST['title']));
    $newbook->appendChild($xml->createElement("author",$_POST['author']));
    $newbook->appendChild($xml->createElement("year",$_POST['year']));
    $newbook->appendChild($xml->createElement("pricee",$_POST['pricee']));

    $books->appendChild($newbook);
    $xml->appendChild($books);
} else {
    // load the xml file
    $xml->load("book.xml");
    $books = $xml->documentElement;

    $newbook = $xml->createElement("book");
    $newbook->appendChild($xml->createElement("title",$_POST['title']));
    $newbook->appendChild($xml->createElement("author",$_POST['author']));
    $newbook->appendChild($xml->createElement("year",$_POST['year']));
    $newbook->appendChild($xml->createElement("pricee",$_POST['pricee']));

    $books->appendChild($newbook);
}
```